# An alternate proof of the fact that a finite field extension is integral over the base field.

Tags: field-theory

Let $F[x]/(p(x))$ be a field extension, where $F$ is a field, and $p(x)$ and irreducible polynomial in $F[x]$. We know that $F[x]/(p(x))$ is integral over $F$.

The standard proof for this uses the property of a vector field that its dimension is constant. Hence, let $a\in F[x]/(p(x))$. Then if the degree of $p(x)$ is $n$, the set $\{1,a,a^2,a^3,\dots,a^n\}$ is linearly dependant. Hence proved.

I was looking for a more direct proof. For example, in the finite field extension $\Bbb{Q}(2^{1/3})$, which is a field extension of degree three, prove that $1+2^{1/3}+5.2^{2/3}$ is integral over $\Bbb{Q}$. In other words I am looking for a proof that presents a generalized algorithm that shows all elements of a finite field extension are integral over the base field.Is such a direct proof available for all terms of a finite field extension?

Answer (score 0):

This would be a direct proof: $F[x]/(p(x))$ is generated by $x$ over $F$ (since it is a root of $p$, which can be assumed to be monic) and $x$ is integral over $F$, hence the extension is integral.